# How to group values in one column based on unique values in another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Name    Pay

---

a   32

---

s   423

---

d   342

---

s   243

---

s   686

---

s   78

I tried the groupby method and looked and binning, combine, transpose, cut, etc. Nothing seems to do the trick. Any suggestions?

a   s   d

---

32  423 342

---

46  243 67

---

NaN 686 NaN

---

NaN 78  NaN

---

NaN 34  NaN

Comment: replace images with text data

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) instead post them as text so as to make them copyable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pandas.pivot_table`:

```py
df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby("Name").cumcount(), values="Pay", columns="Name")
```

Output:

```py
Name     a      d      s
0     32.0  342.0  423.0
1     46.0   67.0  243.0
2      NaN    NaN  686.0
3      NaN    NaN   78.0
4      NaN    NaN   34.0

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about the pivot, you have saved me many hours of digging around!

Comment: No worries:) if it works for you, please mark it as an answer.